# Get Type Of Object which Method Is Called On That

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I've this code block and I want to know the type of object which "Any" method is called on that. For example in this scenario my expected result is DbSet

```
using (AppDbContext context = new AppDbContext() /*Inherited from DbContext of EntityFramework*/)

{
     context.Products.Any(); // context.Products is type of DbSet<Product>
}
```

Or in this example:

```
new int[]{}.Any()
```

my expected result is int[]

Answer (score 1):

Find the `SyntaxNode` you're interested in, get its `Compilation`, then call `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo()`.

Comment: What if the node does not refer to a symbol?

Comment: @KrisVandermotten: Then what do you expect? What kind of node are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Use `SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo`.

For example, if you have a `SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context` and an `ExpressionSyntax expression`, you would do

```
var type = context.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(expression, context.CancellationToken).Type;
```